# problem to build dockerfile to build and create image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, github-actions

I have an error when pushing changes to GitHub, GitHub actions works correctly but when it wants to build DockerFile in DockerFile occurred an error ( */usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.407/NuGet.targets(132,5): warning : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured. [/src/WebApplication2/WebApplication2.csproj]* ):

```
dotnet build ./ -t test
```

Dockerfile:
[image]

at the end of the GitHub actions error it shows "The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore  "WebApplication2/WebApplication2.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1"

how can I fix this issue? thanks.

I expect this error to pass and I can pull docker from GitHub packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by copying the DockerFile to the previous folder